# Flutter get specific data from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need a field in firebase which is their stored:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("comments").doc(IdFromPost).collection(firebaseUser1.uid)
.add({"comment" : messageEditingController.text});
```

does anyone know how I can display the field "comment" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the FlutterFire [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage) on [reading data](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read), that should be something like:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference comments = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('comments');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: comments.doc(IdFromPost).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
          return Text(data['comment']);
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does users mean?

Comment: That was a copy/paste/forgot-to-modify. I updated it now, but in general I'd recommend checking the documentation I linked, as it has quite good examples for the most common use-cases (of which this is one).